# How to handle data for large number of pins on mapview?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkitannotation

I am developing an App that shows a map with annotations. The annotations are in thousands and growing. There are data associated with the annotation pins. I get the data from web service. Should I download all the data for all the pins upfront? That obviously is bad. But how should I do it in an efficient way that when the user zooms in and out the map, there is no lag.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't add all the pins all at once, instead you can load the pins for a certain region first.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. so now I just have to figure out how then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show pins according particular region zoom, instead of showing all pins at one time.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. so now I just have to figure out how then. Thanks. How do I mark this as an answer?

Comment: I have implemented a solution that I am satisfied with. When app opens up, the code will retrieve the pins in the visible region. when the region changes, the code will retrieve again for the pins that in the new visible region.

Comment: @HeatherZ, did you find solution for this, since I am also facing same issue, if you found, can you share the example, it would helpful to me if .you post the answer here. Also it would helpful to others as well who has same issue facing.

Comment: Sorry Anilkumar, I just saw your message. I have moved onto other projects. Please see the message above on April 4 2017. I load the pins for the region in view and then when region changes, I will reload the pin in the new visible region. I wish there were a better or easier way.